# Intel Assembly Programming

Tags: assembly, intel

```
class MyString{
char buf[100];
int len;

boolean append(MyString str){

int k;
if(this.len + str.len>100){

for(k=0; k<str.len; k++){
  this.buf[this.len] = str.buf[k];
  this.len ++;
}
 return false;
}

return true;

}
}
```

Does the above translate to:

```
start:
  push ebp  ; save calling  ebp
  mov ebp, esp  ; setup new ebp
  push esi  ;  
  push ebx  ;  
  mov esi, [ebp + 8]  ;  esi = 'this'
  mov ebx, [ebp + 14]  ;  ebx = str
  mov ecx, 0  ; k=0
  mov edx, [esi + 200] ;  edx = this.len

append:
  cmp edx + [ebx + 200], 100  
  jle ret_true  ; if (this.len + str.len)<= 100 then ret_true
  cmp ecx, edx
  jge ret_false  ; if k >= str.len then ret_false
  mov [esi + edx], [ebx + 2*ecx]  ; this.buf[this.len] = str.buf[k]
  inc edx  ;  this.len++

aux:
  inc ecx  ; k++
  jmp append

ret_true:
  pop ebx  ; restore ebx
  pop esi  ; restore esi
  pop ebp  ; restore ebp
  ret true

ret_false:
  pop ebx  ; restore ebx
  pop esi  ; restore esi
  pop ebp  ; restore ebp
  ret false
```

My greatest difficulty here is figuring out what to push onto the stack and the math for pointers.

NOTE:
I'm not allowed to use global variables and i must assume 32-bit ints, 16-bit chars and 8-bit booleans.

Comment: No, I don't have an assembly compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have an assignement, to create Intel x86 assembly code that performs a string append operation.

If that's true, It might be instructive for you to examine the disassembled output of a C compiler - like the Intel C compiler, or the Microsoft VC++ Express compiler.  Compile some really simple C code, then [disassemble](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers#x86_Disassemblers) and look at the results.

Compilers usually do things a little differently than a human coder would, but in my experience it's not difficult to figure out what's happening in the generated code.  You can see how the ASM code manages the stack, how pointer arithmetic in done, how and when registers are initialized, which registers are used and how, and so on.

A simple C routine might be, your own version of strlen.

Then, add complexity or change things, compile and disassemble again, and see what happens. Like, instead of strlen, make a C routine that returns the last char in a string.

or, if you just want the answer, you could try [Codecodex](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Concatenate_two_strings#X86_Assembly).
:)

Comment: `strlen` tends to produce the confusing `repne`, but +1 anyway.

Comment: I haven't learnt C yet, it would have been really useful here.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, what's confusing about `repne`?

Comment: `repne scasb` isn't exactly mind-bending, but doesn't really capture any important principles either. To the novice, looking up what it does is a bit of a distracting waste of time. Figuring out why the compiler produces it would be somewhat fruitless as it's probably just a special case.